# Haskell loop using recursion

Tags: haskell

Haskell and functional programming is something I am not familiar with, and this semester I got to meet Haskell for the very 1st time. I got unlimited loop when I tried to do a recursion (not very proud of it)

Here's the code

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

mrLoop :: Int -> Int -> IO()
mrLoop a b = do
    if b == 10 then return ()
    else
        print(a*b)
    mrLoop a (b+1)


main = do mrLoop 2 0
```

So I tried to play with it and somehow it works

```
mrLoop :: Int -> Int -> IO()
mrLoop a 10 = return()
mrLoop a b = do
    print(a*b)
    mrLoop a (b+1)
```

But a friend of mine says that's not the Haskell way. So how do I do it in an Haskell way? And why the 1st code doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version recurses forever because the `mrLoop a (b+1)` action is *outside* the `if/else` expression.

In other words, it either does nothing or prints `a*b`, and then it *unconditionally* recurses into `mrLoop a (b+1)`. It'll keep recursing forever.

In the latter example, recursion stops when the pattern-matched function hits the base case where `b` is `10`.

Your friend probably means that this isn't the Haskell way because the Haskell way is to separate pure functions from impure actions.

Try if you can write the recursive 'loop' as a pure function (i.e. without `IO`). What would it return? How could you then use that return value to print a series of results?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning explicitly that `return` does *not* cause the function call to exit, a common misconception with beginners to Haskell.

Comment: so basically, do the recursion on the main function?

Comment: @FARHANDIKAZAHRIRMUFTIGUENIA I'm not sure what you mean, but that doesn't sound right. As my answer implies, you can write recursive pure functions. Most introductions to Haskell will tell you how early in the materials.

Comment: i still dont get it, is it possible for you to show me an example on how to do the loop the haskell way?

Comment: @FARHANDIKAZAHRIRMUFTIGUENIA I could, but I don't think your school would appreciate it if you don't do your exercises yourself.

Comment: the professor didn't give any feedback and choose to continue the course,  while the people who get it didn't want to share. I'm really curious at the moment

Comment: @FARHANDIKAZAHRIRMUFTIGUENIA It'd probably help you best if you read up on the subject, e.g. at http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion